# What does the right hand side of this Stokes' theorem mean?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I'm reading Warner. *"Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups."* I don't understand what the right hand side of the formula in the following theorem means.

> **4.9 Stokes' Theorem II** $\;$ Let $D$ be a regular domain in an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, and let $\omega$ be a smooth $(n-1)$ form of compact support. Then
>   $$\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D}\omega.$$

The book only gives the definition of $\int_D\omega$, where $M$ is an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold, $D$ is a regular domain of $M$, and $\omega$ is a continuous $n$-form with compact support. So if the right hand side of the formula in the above theorem($\int_{\partial D}\omega$) were to make sense, $\omega$ should be an $(n-1)$ form on $\partial D$ ($\partial D$ can be seen as a smooth $(n-1)$ dimensional manifold). But $\omega$ is an $(n-1)$ form on $M$. So how do I identify $\omega$ with an $(n-1)$ form on $\partial D$?

restricting $\omega$ to $\partial D$ wouldn't make $\omega$ an $(n-1)$ form on $\partial D$ because for each $m\in\partial D$, $\omega(m)$ is an element of $\Lambda_{n-1}(M_m^*)$, not $\Lambda_{n-1}((\partial D)_m^*)$.

Comment: See the formulation, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem#Formulation_for_smooth_manifolds_with_boundary). There's a pullback of the inclusion map that should be included on the right.

Comment: Go over the definition of the induced map on forms, then remember that the map on forms induced by the inclusion map is the restriction map. You should see how it all works out.